# Restrict Access to Google Cloud Firestore via VPC network

Tags: google-cloud-filestore

I am saving my backend services data in Firestore. here now I need to restrict access to Firestore within a VPC. 
basically, when connecting to the database from frontend the firebase URL or the database URL shouldn't be public. it should go through a VPC.

Please guide and help me if anyone has an experienced or knowledge on this matter.

Thank You, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Firestore can be used with VPC. As you can see it [the list of what VPC supports](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products) neither Firestore or Datastore are supported.

What you can do instead is possibly have a Cloud Function or GAE service acting as an API and let the service account used by this API be the only one with permissions to access Firestore.

Comment: yeah, seems this is impossible. thank you for the support :)

Comment: You can use VPC with Firestore now. It's still in preview though. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/securing-with-vpc-sc

Comment: FYI, now it's listed as GA